# Adding margins to a component's children in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a few React Native components within a parent `<View>` component, and I wish to apply margins to each one of the `<View>`'s child components. Is there a straightforward way to set props or styles to this `<View>` to produce this result?

Comment: I would suggest you add margin to the layout itself so that all the children will render within its boundary.